# External and internal Identifier

Tags: c, identifier

I know to code in C well but I thought of learning C from the book *C - The Complete Reference* by Herbert Schildt. Here is a quote from Chapter 2:

> In C89, at least the first 6 characters of an external identifier and at
>   least the first 31 characters of an internal identifier will be significant. C99 has increased these values. In C99, an external identifier has at least 31 significant characters, and an internal identifier has at least 63 significant characters.

Can somebody explain what does it mean to be significant?

Comment: Basically this is a known "language bug" in C90, that was fixed in C99. Old C compilers could in theory go haywire when you had identifiers of similar names. In practice, all C90 compilers used limits far beyond C90 minimum requirements.

Answer (score 7):

That means that it is used within the compiler to differ between different names.

E.g. if only the first 6 characters are significant, when having two variables:

```
int abcdef_1;
int abcdef_2;
```

They will be treated as the same variable, and possibly the compiler will generate a warning or error.

About the **minimal** significance:

Maybe the compiler/assembler can handle more, but the linker cannot. Or maybe external tools which are out of control of the manufacturer of the assembler/linker can handle less, thus a minimum value (per type, internal/external) is defined in the C standard(s).

Comment: Interesting, would not they be treated as redefinition, in block scope?

Comment: But the author is saying "atleast the first 31 characters of an internal identifier will be significant.", the word 'atleast' is not making sense to me.

Comment: @RebirthRaven: it means this is a minimum for a conforming compiler.

Comment: @SouravGhosh  ... maybe, or there will be a compiler warning/error.

Comment: @RebirthRaven As per the spec, it mentions the minimum requirement. Implementation is free to choose a bigger value.

Comment: Maybe the compiler/assembler can handle more, but the linker cannot. Or maybe external tools which are out of control of the manufacturer of the assembler/linker can handle less, thus a minimum value (per type, internal/external) is defined in the C standard(s).